# Taxonomy view, display all the nodes that are tagged to all the terms under a particular term

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

Assume that the term hierarchy is as follows

```
Vocabulary = TOPIC

Sports (PARENT TERM)

Football (Child Term)
- node1 (title,teaser,whatever)

Basketball (Child Term)
- node2
- node3
```

I need a view that will accept the term name as the argument and displays all the nodes for a given term and all its subterms.

So if the path of the page is /topic/Sports  where "Sports" is the argument.
I want node1, node2 and node3 to be listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can build view by using Taxonomy: Parent term

After this, we need to alter views query like following...

SELECT node.nid AS nid, node.title AS node_title FROM node node  LEFT JOIN term_node term_node ON node.vid = term_node.vid LEFT JOIN term_data term_data ON term_node.tid = term_data.tid LEFT JOIN term_hierarchy term_hierarchy ON term_data.tid = term_hierarchy.tid WHERE (node.type in ('page')) AND (node.status <> 0) AND (term_hierarchy.parent = 3 **|| term_node.tid = 3**);

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted. But accepting as there are no other answers.